Detect if wifi authentication failed
Want to detect when a Wifi AP is being connected and authentication fails is it due to password failure. Tried using "android.net.wifi.supplicant.STATE_CHANGE" this gives extra **supplicantError **with 1 as output but there's no way to determine for which ssid it was failed. This has been tested on Android 14.
Code snippet:
 WifiManager.SUPPLICANT_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION -> {
                            val supplicantErrorCode =
                                intent.extras?.getInt(WifiManager.EXTRA_SUPPLICANT_ERROR)
                            val newState: SupplicantState? =
                                intent.extras?.getParcelable(WifiManager.EXTRA_NEW_STATE) as? SupplicantState

                            Log.d(
                                TAG,
                                "onReceive: supplicantErrorCode: $supplicantErrorCode , newState: $newState"
                            )
                            
                            if (newState == SupplicantState.DISCONNECTED) {
                                if (supplicantErrorCode == WifiManager.ERROR_AUTHENTICATING) {
                                    Toast.makeText(
                                        this@MainActivity,
                                        "Authentication failed!",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                                    ).show()
                                }
                            } else if (newState == SupplicantState.COMPLETED) {
                                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Connected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                    .show()
                            }

                            Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: ssid:${wifiManager.connectionInfo.ssid}")

